# PSR-2, Line Wrapping for long argument listsl and Netbeans

Tags: php, netbeans

According to the [PSR-2 Standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) on long argument lists:

> Argument lists MAY be split across multiple lines, where each subsequent >line is indented once. When doing so, the first item in the list MUST be >on the next line, and there MUST be only one argument per line.

And that would look like this:

```
<?php
$foo->bar(
    $longArgument,
    $longerArgument,
    $muchLongerArgument
);
```

However, in netbeans, while I have PSR-2 installed into the formatter, when I allow it to autoformat, I get:

```
$foo->bar($longArgument, $longerArgument, $muchLongerArgument);
```

I can change it to look like this:

```
$foo->bar(
     $longArgument
     , $longerArgument
     , $muchLongerArgument
    );
```

But this violates the standard.  I can also set it to *always* line-break with a method call, but then I get:

```
    $foo->bar($longArgument,
     $longerArgument,
     $muchLongerArgument);
```

Which also does not conform to the standard.  It also automatically changes *all* method calls, while I want to only change method calls that I deem too long, and I want them to break as described above.

Is there a way to force netbeans to either break in the described way automatically when the line becomes too long ("Wrapping" set to "Too long" doesn't do it), and if not, is there a way I can prevent it from automatically putting my reformatted back onto one line without resorting to a different editor, or turning autoformat off?

Answer (score 0):

Netbeans hasn't good code formatting tools for PHP PSR standards and it's difficult to force it to do. Much more better options is use external tool.

That's look fine:
[NetBeans PHP CS Fixer Plugin](https://github.com/junichi11/netbeans-php-cs-fixer-plugin)

You should just configure you setting and done.